# Entity Framework Data Source for whole solution having multiple PRISM based projects

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, datasource, prism

My application is WPF(C#) based using Microsoft PRISM technology. As per PRISM style my solution has many projects(Modules). In order to use WPF+EF Code First databinding, i have made a Common project for dbcontext purpose and created EF Code First data source based on it. Now i am unable to access this data source in my modules(various projects of the solution). Even i have created references from the modules to the Common project but still data source is not visible.
Is there any standard method of making EF data source visible for all the projects of the solution? Thanks!

Comment: All you should have to do is add a reference to the EF project in every project that needs it, and include the appropriate `using` statement in the classes that need to use the EF data context.

Comment: Thanks Tony for your quick response but i already have mentioned in my question that all the projects have reference to the EF project and i also have added "using" EF project statements. When i select EF project the data source is shown in the Data Source window of Visual Studio but whenever any other project is selected the message shown in Data Source window is "Your project currently has no data sources associated with it. Add a new data source ... "

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to edit the data source from a project that references it or from the project where you created it?  Since the data source is created in only one project, you should only see it listed in that project.  The rest of the projects will know about the EF classes, but not about the data source itself.  If you want to change the data source, you need to go back to the project that defines it to do that.  Your other projects should be able to create EF queries with no more than you have.

Comment: No i don't want to edit. One solution may be every project should have its own entity and DbContext class and based on that data source. But in that case using Code First scheme isolated table will be created for every module in the database because inter dependency between them will be missing. Second solution (which i have adopted) is to bring all entity classes in common project and make DbContext class in that project. So data source based on that project should be for whole solution (May be my understanding is wrong or EF does not support enterprise application having multiple projects)